# Statement for output in prolog

Tags: prolog

I try to sort a list of numbers like `[1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,6,7]` in this increasing order into 2 other list `Unique` and `NotUnique`, which just to find out if a number appears more than once in the list. `1` will go into `Unique` list, `3,3` will go into `NotUnique` list.

I have made changes due to suggestions, but I kept have `_G1678` and `_G1708` at the end of the sorted list, what are these?

```
 ?- removeUni([1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6],A,B).
A = [1, 2, 4|_G1678],
B = [3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6|_G1708].
```

Here is my code of `removeUni`:

```
removeUni([],[],[]).
removeUni([X],[X],[]).    
removeUni([X1,X2],[X1,X2|Uni],D):-
    X1 < X2,
    !.
removeUni([X1,X2],Uni,[X1,X2|D]):-
    X1 =:= X2,
    !.
    removeUni([X],[X|Uni],D).
removeUni([X1,X2,X3|Q],[X1,X2|Uni],D):-
    X1 < X2,
    X2 < X3,
    removeUni([X3|Q],Uni,D),
    !.
removeUni([X1,X2,X3|Q],[X1|Uni],D):-
    X1 < X2,
    X2 == X3,
    removeUni([X2,X3|Q],Uni,D),
    !.
removeUni([X1,X2,X3|Q],Uni,[X1|D]):-
    X1 == X2,
    X2 == X3,
    removeUni([X2,X3|Q],Uni,D),
    !.
removeUni([X1,X2,X3|Q],Uni,[X1,X2|D]):-
    X1 == X2,
    X2 < X3,
    removeUni([X3|Q],Uni,D),
    !.
```

Comment: `removeUni([X],[X],[X]).` isn't correct. If you have a list of one element, `[X]`, then `X` is unique. So this should be `removeUni([X], [X], []).`. And you shouldn't have `removeUni([],Uni,D).` at all. It says that if you have an empty list, then the list of unique and non-unique elements are any lists that you like. You are also saying you are trying to sort a list of numbers, but your predicate seems to assume the numbers are already sorted. Can you clarify?

Comment: Minor observation: The clause with `=:=` should have a `,` in place of the `.`

Comment: When you get results with `_xxx` variables, it means they are uninstantiated. Your very first clause `removeUni([X1,X2],[X1,X2|Uni],D)` does not instantiate `D`. You are probably getting a "singleton variable" warning. You need to heed these warnings and resolve them.